# How to send a date to server in ASP.net as JSON

Tags: jquery, asp.net, http, post, json.net

Okay, i'm really confused about sending my date to server and receiving the data back. It just doesn't recognize it.

1. How to 'post' my date if i already use 'get' method for getting a link for request?
2. When i 'get' the date, the server receives this in `"/Date(875948900000)/"` this format and can't recognize it, so i can't get my data back from it. The dataType is JSON.
3. What should i write in my Ajax controller, HttpPost code?
   Sorry for maybe stupid questions but i'm a newbie and just want to understand this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a big difference between using GET Or POST, GET method is that GET carries request parameter appended in URL string while POST carries request parameter in message body which makes it more secure way of transferring data.

But, you can use this code that sends a date using ajax and JSON to c# and re-send from c# back to ajax using Success

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "page.aspx/SETDATE",
            data: JSON.stringify({ 'Date': DateThatWillBeSent}),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) { 
                alert(msg);
            }
        });
```

and in c# use

```
 [WebMethod]
        public static string SETDATE(string Date)
        {
            try
            {
               return Date;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { 
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I do get this error: POST http://localhost:5050/doc_api/api/BalanceAjax 404 (Not Found)

Comment: First of all, you are sending me a local link I can't check it, secondly, did you make the function a static method? and you used it as a static public method just like I've written in the code?. Last but not least the error not found means that the method wasn't found in you're code kindly use for testing purpose my code and then edit it just to make sure everything is working fine